# MEF2 & Caliburn.Micro - IWindowManager and IEventAggregator are not importing to ShellViewModel

Tags: c#, mef, caliburn.micro

I cannot get MEF2 to import a WindowManager or EventAggregator to my ShellViewModel. All my own Classes seem to work fine.

I've setting up my project to use MEF2 (System.ComponentModel.Composition and children). I followed the [Customizing The Bootstrapper](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/bootstrapper) document to start as well as Tim Corey's [From Zero to Proficient with MEF](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/376033/From-Zero-to-Proficient-with-MEF), and realized that these are MEF1. I did some reading, [MEF 2 Preview Beginners Guide](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/366583/MEF-2-Preview-Beginners-Guide) and [Managed Extensibility Framework Improvements in .NET 4.5](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/02/12/mef-convention-model.aspx), replaced CompositionBatch with RegistrationBuilder, and got rid of the suggested Class and Property Attributes, to favour RegistrationBuilder's Fluid API for configuring imports and exports.

I get a NullReferenceException in the OnActivate override in the ShellViewModel, when it attempts to use _eventAggregator. The imports were never made.

If I run this by commenting out the OnActivate() and OnDeactivate(), it launches and displays a blank window, so it is loading the shell properly. It just isn't importing any dependencies.

Here is the simplest Bootstrapper and ViewModel to show the problem.

## Bootstrapper.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using Caliburn.Micro;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Registration;
using System.Reflection;
using MEF2Test.ViewModels;

namespace MEF2Test
{
    public class MefBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
    {
        private CompositionContainer _container;

        public MefBootstrapper()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        protected override void Configure()
        {
            RegistrationBuilder cmBuilder = new RegistrationBuilder();
            RegistrationBuilder cmpBuilder = new RegistrationBuilder();
            RegistrationBuilder vmBuilder = new RegistrationBuilder();

            cmBuilder.ForTypesDerivedFrom<IEventAggregator>().Export<IEventAggregator>();
            cmpBuilder.ForTypesDerivedFrom<IWindowManager>().Export<IWindowManager>();
            vmBuilder.ForTypesDerivedFrom<IShell>().Export<IShell>();

            // These added based on a reference I read, to use ImportProperty
            vmBuilder.ForTypesDerivedFrom<IShell>().ImportProperty<IEventAggregator>(x => x.EventAggregator);
            vmBuilder.ForTypesDerivedFrom<IShell>().ImportProperty<IWindowManager>(x => x.WindowManager);

            AggregateCatalog catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
            AssemblyCatalog cmAssembly = new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(IEventAggregator).GetTypeInfo().Assembly, cmBuilder);
            AssemblyCatalog cmpAssembly = new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(IWindowManager).GetTypeInfo().Assembly, cmpBuilder);
            AssemblyCatalog vmAssembly = new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(MefBootstrapper).GetTypeInfo().Assembly, vmBuilder);

            catalog.Catalogs.Add(cmAssembly);
            catalog.Catalogs.Add(cmpAssembly);
            catalog.Catalogs.Add(vmAssembly);

            _container = new CompositionContainer(catalog, CompositionOptions.DisableSilentRejection | CompositionOptions.IsThreadSafe);
        }

        protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> SelectAssemblies()
        {
            return new[] {
                typeof(IWindowManager).GetTypeInfo().Assembly,
                typeof(IEventAggregator).GetTypeInfo().Assembly,
                typeof(MefBootstrapper).GetTypeInfo().Assembly
            };
        }

        protected override object GetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
        {
            string contract = string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) ? AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType) : key;
            var exports = _container.GetExportedValues<object>(contract);

            if (exports.Any())
                return exports.First();

            throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not locate any instances of contract {0}", contract));
        }

        protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type serviceType)
        {
            return _container.GetExports<object>(AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType));
        }

        protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
        {
            _container.SatisfyImportsOnce(instance);
        }

        protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayRootViewFor<IShell>();
        }
    }
}
```

## ShellViewModel.cs

```
using Caliburn.Micro;

namespace MEF2Test.ViewModels
{
    public class ShellViewModel : Screen, IShell
    {
        private IWindowManager _windowManager;
        private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

        public ShellViewModel()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnActivate()
        {
            base.OnActivate();
            _eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
        }

        protected override void OnDeactivate(bool close)
        {
            base.OnDeactivate(close);
            _eventAggregator.Unsubscribe(this);
        }

        // These 2 Properties added based on a reference I read, to use ImportProperty
        public IEventAggregator EventAggregator
        {
            get { return _eventAggregator; }
            set { _eventAggregator = value; }
        }

        public IWindowManager WindowManager
        {
            get { return _windowManager; }
            set { _windowManager = value; }
        }

    }

    public interface IShell
    {
        // These added based on a reference I read, to use ImportProperty
        IEventAggregator EventAggregator { get; set; }
        IWindowManager WindowManager { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I resolved this by changing the 2 ImportProperty lines from `ForTypesDerivedFrom<IShell>` to `ForType<ShellViewModel>`. Why can I not use ForTypesDerivedFrom? I don't want to specific a concrete type here. If anyone wants to submit this as an answer and explain why, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. For some reason, I must use:

```
ForType<ConcreteType>.ImportProperty<Interface>(x => x.PublicPropertyToSetInterface);
```

when registering the Imports. This has gotten my simple example working, so that answers my question. My actual project still suffers from a

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Lazy`1[System.Object]' to type 'Caliburn.Micro.IWindowManager'.'
```

error, but that's probably something I've missed or misrepresented in my registrations.